# Typescript type check on callback

Tags: typescript

I have recently started learning Typescript and ran into this problem that I do not understand conceptually. Is it wrong to define parameter type for this function?

```
setTimeout((a: string) => {
    console.log(a); // ==> Prints 5 as a number
}, 1, 5);
```

Why isn't there type checking performed when calling callback?

How would I go about making typescript throw an error?

What are my solutions in general, when encountering something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#32186](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32186).  The [typings for `setTimeout()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/14fb0b06df49ff50c778a8deeac6447236922097/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17376) look like

```
setTimeout(handler: TimerHandler, timeout?: number, ...arguments: any[]): number;
```

which accepts any argument list whatsoever, without caring about the types.  And `TimerHandler` is [defined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/14fb0b06df49ff50c778a8deeac6447236922097/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18727) as just

```
type TimerHandler = string | Function
```

which uses [the unsafe and untyped `Function` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function).  So `setTimeout()` is unfortunately very loosely typed in TypeScript.  Often in situations like this you could use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add better call signatures, but in this case nothing will stop the compiler from falling back to the unsafe call signature.

This is just a limitation in TS, it seems.  The issue is listed as being in the "Backlog", so it's not slated to be addressed anytime soon. You could go to microsoft/TypeScript#32186 and give it a  and show support for it being fixed, but it's not likely to change much.

For now there are only workarounds.

---

You *could* decide to use your own local copy of [the `lib.dom.ts` library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/14fb0b06df49ff50c778a8deeac6447236922097/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), where you modify the definition of `safeTimeout()`, but that would be very annoying to maintain.

A workaround you could use is to wrap `setTimeout` in your own function that is more strongly typed, and then use only that  Perhaps something like this:

```
const safeSetTimeout: <A extends any[]>(
    handler: (...args: A) => void, timeout?: number, ...args: A
) => number = setTimeout;
```

That uses [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to strongly type the `args` expected by the `handler` callback to be same as that passed as the `args` passed to `setTimeout()` itself.  Let's see it work:

```
safeSetTimeout((a: string) => {
    console.log(a);
}, 1, 5); // <-- error!  number is not assignable to string
//    ~
```

Great, we get the expected compiler error on `5`, saying that it should be a `string` and not a `number`.  That's about as good as it gets for now, unfortunately.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGAzApgZWVAKgSwLbJAFcoAuGAHgEEZkAPKZMAEwhnjAE8BtAXQD4AFAFgAUDHEwAFuyYAbZACcyAgHRr4CgOYQylAJQwAvHxgA3ENiYAaGFDwFiAfjJhCuAEaKbalRu27RA2MYVw9FIzgMHHwiKABuUUSRBBR0LHtYgQF4MmgFbDBNIJMAb1EJGFBIEHkVWRBNbL0EkQBfGwBGGwBWZpgAen6KAFphmgUFEAUAQnFQzwUYbFYwEFh4CAhsTTB4d3lbEDgofMKkoA)

Comment: If I were to modify the library (I won't), changing setTimeout definition to  `declare function setTimeout<A extends any[]>(handler: (...args: A) => void, timeout?: number, ...arguments: A): number;`  would fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, it would fix the problem.